# How can i send different users to separate view controllers using firebase and Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am fairly new to coding and have started using firebase as a back end server for an application i am creating in Xcode using swift.

The app itself will have one login page but 3 separate types of users. The admin will have different permissions to the other 2 users.

The code I currently have is:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: username!, password: password!, completion: { (user, error) in
    if error == nil {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AdminVC")
        self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)                
    }
```

The code is getting the email and password for the authentication page. But because of the 3 different types of users I don't want them all going to the 'AdminVC' view controller.

Is there a way of getting the 2 other users to go to their own view controllers using this authentication method?

Comment: You can use a swich-case statement block inside the else block. Compare the username with each case and prepare the vc accordingly.

Comment: Would that need to be done with ever single user?

Comment: Not every single user, but every single **type** of user. I assume you have 5 types all together? 3 user types and 2 admin types? Then setup 5 cases, where you compare the login with the type of user and show the vc accordingly. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear in the question, i will have 3 types of users. Admin, Teacher and Student, as the authentication page only shows the email and password i don't know how to separate

Comment: them as 3 different users. with the case would that use swift code that looks at which email has logged in?

Comment: You can use the email, if the emails are significantly different BUT better way would be to have a custom variable that you can store on firebase when a user signs up. So lets say, when a teacher signs up for an account for the first time, you can save it as a teacher. And when the teacher logs in, you request that information from the server and using that info, you display the viewcontroller that best fits what you want to show.

Comment: Ask yourself this question, if you were to look at all the users in the server, how would you know which is which? By email? By sign up date? How can you differentiate the user from the admin and the teacher? That is what you should setup the case to be. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The users would be know by their emails. The problem is that firebase shows all the emails in the authentication page so the code I'm using is getting the all the emails from the authentication page.

Comment: You need to categorize the emails somehow... That is the only way to only present three seperate vc's..

Comment: if i put in the if statment the admin's Uid and if that = the email and password send to the AdminVC then do that again for the teachers could that work?

Comment: other than that i don't know how to categorise the emails and that what i am stuck with.

Comment: Yes that could work but that's not a good way. You want to make it abstract enough that you never check emails, only check roles. If it's a basic app then you could get away with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store a type for a user you have to use the database. Like this
[image]

When the user logs in, get the value from the database for the path "users/<userId>/type". Then use a switch statement to redirect to the correct view controller.

Here's the full code

```
 // Sign in to Firebase
 FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: "ntoonio@gmail.com", password: "Password123", completion: {
     (user, error) in
         // If there's no errors
         if error == nil {
             // Get the type from the database. It's path is users/<userId>/type.
             // Notice "observeSingleEvent", so we don't register for getting an update every time it changes.
             FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users/\(user!.uid)/type").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
                 (snapshot) in

                 switch snapshot.value as! String {
                 // If our user is admin...
                 case "admin":
                     // ...redirect to the admin page
                     let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "adminVC")
                     self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                 // If out user is a regular user...
                 case "user":
                     // ...redirect to the user page
                     let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userVC")
                     self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                 // If the type wasn't found...
                 default:
                     // ...print an error
                     print("Error: Couldn't find type for user \(user!.uid)")
                 }
            })
        }
    })
```

Instead of the whole switch statement you can do

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(snapshot.value)_View")
self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Warning! This will crash if the type isn't found. But that's fixable :)

Comment: because i am also new to firebase i am also finding it difficult to add data to the database section as its my first time working with JSON trees. Would it be possible to show me how i could input the types of user in the database.

Comment: In the switch statement, if the default block is triggered it means there's no data (since we will only input "admin" or "user", you can add as many types as you want) and it's a new user. Here you can set the type with FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(["type": "<type here>"])

Comment: what if i were to input the data manually into the database through the firebase console? would this still work?

Comment: Yes, and that would make more sense since you don't want the user to be able to choose to be admin :)

Comment: This is going a bit of topic. If you have any further questions you can check my profile for another way to contact me :)

Comment: I have been trying to add the information into the database for an hour, every time i try to  add another type ('teacher') to the 'user' node the the admin type disappears. its so frustrating :(

Comment: You can only have one "type" key... but psst ^^

Comment: Thanks i have sent an email :)