# How to manage user access level? Determine if he is admin or basic user

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to Firebase, I am using Swift 4, There are lots of examples to do basic user authentication but I would like to know how I can create users as either admin or with basic access level and I would like to be able to determine when the user is logged in if he is admin or just a basic user?

Any concrete example on github based on KSigWyatt's answer below would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39063833/4916627) i wrote. The second part may give you some ideas about how to do this.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look for sure, I was just hoping there is a Swift version of the example.

Comment: This question has been asked many many times here on SO. There are a number of fantastic solutions - just do a search on [firebase][swift]admin user and look through the examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i send different users to separate view controllers using firebase and Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406673/how-can-i-send-different-users-to-separate-view-controllers-using-firebase-and-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use `Firebase Database` and save an attribute (something like `isAdmin` as a `bool` flag) for the user permissions.

There's no way to save application specific user attributes within `Authentication`. The only data that Auth stores are things like email address', social accounts, passwords of the user accounts.

### First

Try something like this for your database:

```
Database/
    Users/
        UID/  -- Each of these are Unique
            id: -Lrye7w8qtrewfr
            isAdmin: true
            ...
        ...
    ...
```

#### Afterward...

Using ref.observeSingleEvent() once the user is logged in will return the snapshot for the child *Document/Table* `"User"` and the second child of the user's `UID` via `Auth.auth().currentUser.uid`

Capture the return using the same key as the attribute in the database. `["isAdmin"]`

Comment: This depends on the security rules. If a user has rights to change his own data (i have seen this a lot) he can give himself admin rights.

Comment: Thank KSignWyatt, this makes perfect sense. As I am still learning about Firebase I am wondering if you have come across examples on github or else where that do this sort of thing. Thanks again.